Parsing/comparing values from paginator in AWS Golang SDK
I am trying to do what is shown here but for DescribeNetworkInterfaces for all regions in the account using a paginator. The following code doesn't compile:
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/ec2"
)

func main() {


    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to load AWS SDK config, %v", err)
    }

    ec2Client := ec2.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    availableRegions, err := ec2Client.DescribeRegions(context.TODO(), &ec2.DescribeRegionsInput{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to get AWS regions, %v", err)
    }

    for _, region := range availableRegions.Regions {
        fmt.Println("Region Name :", *region.RegionName)

        ec2Client := ec2.NewFromConfig(cfg, func(o *ec2.Options) {
            o.Region = (*region.RegionName)
        })

        describeIntefacesPaginator := ec2.NewDescribeNetworkInterfacesPaginator(ec2Client, &ec2.DescribeNetworkInterfacesInput{}, func(o *ec2.DescribeNetworkInterfacesPaginatorOptions) {
            o.Limit = 1000
        })

        for describeIntefacesPaginator.HasMorePages() {
            output, err := describeIntefacesPaginator.NextPage(context.TODO())
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error", err)
                break
            }

            for _, interface := range output.NetworkInterfaces {
               fmt.Println(*interface.NetworkInterfaceId, "-" *interface.InterfaceType)
            }

        }
    }

}

The compiler complains that there is a error in the for loop:
2024-04-01 16:52:08.993 [info] test.go:46:21 syntax error: unexpected :=, expected {
If a remove the for loop and output to JSON using the encoding package I do get output (I currently have 2 ENIs in ap-south-1:
output2, err := json.Marshal(output)

if err != nil {
   fmt.Println("Unable to convert the struct to a JSON string")
} else {
   fmt.Println(string(output2) + "\n")
}

{"NetworkInterfaces":[{"Association":null,"Attachment":null,"AvailabilityZone":"ap-south-1a","ConnectionTrackingConfiguration":null,"DenyAllIgwTraffic":null,"Description":"test2","Groups":[{"GroupId":"sg-0242772b747b89a45","GroupName":"default"}],"InterfaceType":"interface","Ipv4Prefixes":null,"Ipv6Address":null,"Ipv6Addresses":[],"Ipv6Native":null,"Ipv6Prefixes":null,"MacAddress":"02:2d:44:db:66:9d","NetworkInterfaceId":"eni-069434f3d842b5ce4","OutpostArn":null,"OwnerId":"<redacted>","PrivateDnsName":"ip-172-31-34-44.ap-south-1.compute.internal","PrivateIpAddress":"172.31.34.44","PrivateIpAddresses":[{"Association":null,"Primary":true,"PrivateDnsName":"ip-172-31-34-44.ap-south-1.compute.internal","PrivateIpAddress":"172.31.34.44"}],"RequesterId":"<redacted>","RequesterManaged":false,"SourceDestCheck":true,"Status":"available","SubnetId":"subnet-04d1989d5b4bb8a93","TagSet":[],"VpcId":"vpc-0e9a0e28dad668f8a"},{"Association":null,"Attachment":null,"AvailabilityZone":"ap-south-1c","ConnectionTrackingConfiguration":null,"DenyAllIgwTraffic":null,"Description":"test","Groups":[{"GroupId":"sg-0242772b747b89a45","GroupName":"default"}],"InterfaceType":"interface","Ipv4Prefixes":null,"Ipv6Address":null,"Ipv6Addresses":[],"Ipv6Native":null,"Ipv6Prefixes":null,"MacAddress":"06:22:17:0b:8b:d3","NetworkInterfaceId":"eni-0c03afbd1d2638e74","OutpostArn":null,"OwnerId":"<redacted>","PrivateDnsName":"ip-172-31-24-26.ap-south-1.compute.internal","PrivateIpAddress":"172.31.24.26","PrivateIpAddresses":[{"Association":null,"Primary":true,"PrivateDnsName":"ip-172-31-24-26.ap-south-1.compute.internal","PrivateIpAddress":"172.31.24.26"}],"RequesterId":"<redacted>","RequesterManaged":false,"SourceDestCheck":true,"Status":"available","SubnetId":"subnet-09e693c955f141ea7","TagSet":[],"VpcId":"vpc-0e9a0e28dad668f8a"}],"NextToken":null,"ResultMetadata":{}}

The end goal is to able if/else or compare values in returned struct. Should I store the output from the paginator in a map then perform operations on it instead?
Edit: Now using:
for _, netInterface := range output.NetworkInterfaces {
    fmt.Println(*netInterface.NetworkInterfaceId, "-", *netInterface.Association)

I am trying to test whether *netInterface.Association is null/exists in the struct. If I convert it JSON and print it out it will show "Association":null but Association is of type *NetworkInterfaceAssociation. From the posting here using:
if *netInterface.Association == nil
Is flagged by the compiler as a mismatched type and:
if netInterface.Association == nil
Will compile but will cause an invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference error.

interface is a Go reserved word and can't be used as a variable name.

The error is on the test.go file, not in the code per se. Check what you've wrote in test.go:46:21
